# Cornerstone library for DICOM - display coronal and sagital views

Tags: dicom, cornerstone

I am using cornerstone to display DICOM images on a browser.

I am able to load the image but want different views. They're technically called - coronal view and saggital view.

Is it possible using cornerstone library? IF yes, how ?

Comment: Reconstructions along the axes are usually achieved using an MPR - Multi-planar reformatting. I am not familiar with cornerstone library, so can't help you further.

Comment: I know this is an old question but I believe the [OHIF Viewer](http://viewer.ohif.org/) does what you want and it is cornerstone based but uses MANY other libraries with it. I am no help beyond that. :P

Answer (score 2):

I personally haven't tried but as Pavlo Dyban mentioned you need MPR reconstruction to do this, for that you'd have to parse the whole set of slices and construct the other orientations. I say *parse* because loading all the slices could be very demanding regarding memory resources but faster in terms of retrieving information, whereas reconstructing slices on demand will be very demanding in terms of network traffic since you'll have to load all *axial* slices to compute a single coronal or sagittal one.

Comment: Cornerstone doesn't support MPR. Papaya supports it.

Answer (score 1):

The demo you can see here http://chafey.github.io/cornerstoneDemo/# doesn't show multiplanar reformatting as an option.

Comment: Hi Jhon,
I have checked the link but it is not working getting CORS error.

Comment: Even if it's not working, it still doesn't support multiplaner reformatting as posted above by chrisrhyno2003.